# Run jmeter thread for specific period and restart after 6days

Tags: jmeter

I have a thread group that is running non-stop in a VM to simulate user behavior. However I need to stop it after 6 days, since the user token expires (after 6 days) and make the user login again. My thread sequence is as follows-

```
1. Login (extracts session token and use it in subsequent calls)
2. HTTP req 1
3. Loop controller 
    a. http req 2
    b. http req 3...
```

Is there a way or script that I can use to auto-stop the thread group after 6 days and auto-restart it again?
The Scheduler on thread group just stops it after a certain time, but I need to auto-restart the thread group again.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to run JMeter test for 6 days, then restart it you can configure your [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to run for 6 days

[image]

and schedule the test execution using your operating system task scheduling mechanisms like [crontab](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) for Unix and derivatives or [Windows Task Scheduler](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-automated-task-using-task-scheduler-windows-10). One more option is putting your JMeter test under orchestration of a Continuous Integration server like [Jenkins](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/continuous-integration-101-how-run-jmeter-jenkins)

---

If for some reason the above options are not suitable, i.e. you don't have permissions to install 3rd-party software or add a scheduled tasks on OS level what's the problem in putting the `Login (extracts session token and use it in subsequent calls)` into a separate Thread Group and use [Constant Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) or [Flow Control Action Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) in order to make this `Login` to fire once per 6 days? The token and stuff can be passed to the "main" Thread Group via [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) or [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/)

Comment: I have put the Login in another thread group like you suggested and the remaining http requests in another group and used the setproperty. I am struggling with how to set up the login thread group to run once every 'n' days.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your original Test Plan structure in one of the following ways:

```
1. Login
2. HTTP req 1
3. While Controller 
    a. http req 2
    b. http req 3...
```

The While Controller could run for 6 days after which the outer Thread Group would loop around for another login.

The While condition would have to compare the time difference between the current time and `TESTSTART.MS` (see https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedprops) and take into account the number of previous logins i.e. number of Thread Group iterations (e.g. `__jm__Thread Group__idx`).

```
1. If Controller
    a. Login
    b. HTTP req 1
2. http req 2
3. http req 3...
```

Alternatively, an If Controller could run only once every 6 days with a condition similar to the above.